# how can i input a text from a text file (c)

Tags: c

how can i input a text from a text file using fgets while using a 2D array for input?

```
main(){

    char text[1000][1000];
    FILE *fptr;
    char fname[100];
    printf("input file name:");
    scanf("%s",fname);
    fptr=fopen(fname,"w");
    if(fptr==NULL){
        printf("Error in opening file");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `else` since the first condition called `exit` and so overcomplicates the code. Instead, iterate a loop based on the return value from `fgets` such as `while(fgets(. . .) != NULL) { /* process the text line */ }`

Comment: regardless of what visual studio will allow, this:  `main(){` is not a valid signature for the `main()` function.  All instances of a `main()` function have a return type of `int`

Comment: the posted code is missing the `#include` statements for the header files: `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Impossible to help without some more information: (1) What does the data in the text file look like (i.e., are they 'lines' of text ending in LF or CR-LF, or are they just one million characters with no newlines, ...?). (2) How do you want the data in your text file to be placed within your 1000x1000 character array? Should each 'line' in the text file be placed into a 'row' in the grid, starting from row 0? (3) If a text file line was longer than 1000 characters, should it 'wrap' to the next array row, or be truncated? (4) Should data in the array be null-terminated?

Comment: @user3629249 - I think *minimal* actually means you can leave out the header files, since (1) the question isn't "why doesn't this work" or "why won't this compile" and (2) it's so obvious which files would need to be included that you yourself named them. This question is about *how do I do this*, so what's there is plenty as far as completeness is concerned, IMO.

Comment: @ScottSmith,  NO, 'minimal` means to leave out those parts of the code that are not relevant to the problem. but `complete` and `verifiable` means the code needs to actually cleanly compile

Comment: @user3629249 - `int` is the default return type in ANSI C; the function definition is valid. Even if it weren't, being pedantic about details doesn't help OP; the question isn't *what's wrong with this code*, it's *how do I do this*

Comment: @ScottSmith,  Ok, "how do I do this?"  Of course, the OP needs to learn to write code that a modern compiler will not complain about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for errors
4. properly cleans up before exiting
5. documents which header file exposed which functions and which #defines

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // FILE, printf(), scanf(), fprintf()
                      // fopen(), fclose(), stderr, fflush()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, realloc()
#include <string.h>   // strdup()

#define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 99
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 1000

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fptr;
    char filename[ MAX_FILENAME_LEN +1 ];

    printf("input file name:");
    fflush( stdout );
    if( scanf( "%99s", filename ) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to read the file name\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    fptr = fopen( filename, "w" );
    if( !fptr )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    char **savedText = NULL;
    size_t numLines = 0;
    char line[ MAX_LINE_LEN ];

    while( fgets( line, sizeof(line), fptr ) )
    {
        char *temp = realloc( savedText, (numLines+1)*sizeof(char*) );
        if( !temp )
        {
            perror( "realloc failed" );
            fclose( fptr );
            for( size_t i=0; i<numLines; i++ )
            {
                free( savedText+i );
            }
            free( savedText );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, realloc successful

        *savedText = temp;
        savedText[ numLines ] = strdup( line );
        if( !savedText+numLines )
        {
            perror( "strdup failed" );
            fclose( fptr );
            for( size_t i=0; i<numLines; i++ )
            {
                free( savedText+i );
            }
            free( savedText );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, strdup successful

        numLines++;

    } // end while()

    fclose( fptr );
    for( size_t i=0; i<numLines; i++ )
    {
        free( savedText[ i ] );
    }
    free( savedText );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note: `strdup()` is a posix function.  Read the MAN page for how to expose that function.

Comment: Note: the function: `fgets()` inputs everything on the line, including the trailing newline